# Java Swing UI Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am creating a basic user interface in Swing and was hoping for some help. Below is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

My code currently is as follows:

```
package testui;

import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestUI{

    private JTextField outputArea = new JTextField();
    private JTextField errorReportArea = new JTextField();
    
    private JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    
    private JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Item Name");
    private JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Number of units (or Volume in L)");
    private JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price per unit (Or L) in pence");
    
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField numberField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField priceField = new JTextField(10);
    
    private JButton addVolumeButton = new JButton("Add by Volume");
    private JButton addNumberButton = new JButton("Add by number of units");         
    
    public TestUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fuel Station");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        errorReportArea.setEditable(false);
        
        inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        inputPanel.add(nameLabel);
        inputPanel.add(nameField);
        inputPanel.add(numberLabel);
        inputPanel.add(numberField);
        inputPanel.add(priceLabel);
        inputPanel.add(priceField);
        inputPanel.add(addVolumeButton);
        inputPanel.add(addNumberButton);
        
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        contentPane.add(outputArea);
        contentPane.add(errorReportArea);
        contentPane.add(inputPanel);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestUI test1 = new TestUI();
    }
    
}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

So what I would like to do is set a specific size for the top two JTextFields, as the top one will contain multiple lines of text, and the one below will contain just one line of text. I am unsure how to do this without using setSize, as I have been told it is bad coding practice to use this.

I would also like to add some padding between the JLabels, JTextFields and JButtons in the bottom JPanel.

If anyone could give me some suggestions on resizing these components I would be most grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you want your textfields to be multilined, use [JTextAreas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html). JTextFields are single lined only.
- Your components are right next to each other which isn't the same look as your intended outcome. There may be some method that gives your components some breathing room before you would call `frame.pack()`
- Look for any method that can make a component fill the total amount of room it's given; especially when you want something to fill a large chunk of space.
- You can set the number of columns instead of using `setSize()` for your JTextFields/JTextAreas. Just saying.
- Reviewing all of [Java's Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) would help you get a grasp of the capabilities and use cases for each layout manager

Comment: +1 for text area. But please take out _"remove the frame.pack()"_. The frame _should_ be packed. Using a BorderLayout along with the row/column hints of the text area should provide the OP with what they want

Comment: *fixed. I think in most circumstances you should use `frame.pack()` just so you have no empty room floating around.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have changed the first textfield to a textarea, and used outputArea.setRows(30) to set its size. After looking at the Layout Managers, I also changed the boxlayout of my bottom panel to a FlowLayout, which works well and also includes a 5px padding on components by default

Answer (score 0):

There are a few layout managers that are flexible enough to perform this, such as Mig, Gridbag, and [SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html).

In your case, you'd have the following constraints:

`outputarea` - `south` border constrained to be ###px from the north border of the `contentPane`

`errorReportArea` - `north` border constrained to be 0px from `outputarea`'s south, and `south` border constrained to be 0px from `inputPanel`'s north.

`inputPanel` - `north` border constrained to be ##px from the south border of the `contentPane`.

GUI builders such as [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) will allow you to do this pretty quickly. You just drop in the layout onto the contentPane and then set the constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately we have only studied Swing on the course I am undertaking, therefore that is all we are allowed to use

Comment: @user3371750 [javax.swing.SpringLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html) is part of Swing:

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a box layout look at the glue and rigidArea methods in [Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html).  If you can use other layouts, go with those suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution with the `MigLayout` manager.

Here are some recommendations:

- Put application code outside the constructor; in the solution, the code
  is placed in the `initUI()` method.
- The application should be started on EDT by calling the 
  `EventQueue.invokeLater()`. (See the `main()` method of the provided solution.)
- Use a modern, flexible layout manager: `MigLayout`, `GroupLayout`, or `FormLayout`.
  Take some time to study them to fully understand the layout management process. It
  is important have a good understanding of this topic.
- Shorten the labels; use more descriptive tooltips 
  instead.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutSolution extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea outputArea;
    private JTextField errorReportField;

    private JLabel nameLabel;
    private JLabel numberLabel;
    private JLabel priceLabel;

    private JTextField nameField;
    private JTextField numberField;
    private JTextField priceField;

    private JButton addVolumeButton;
    private JButton addNumberButton;

    public MigLayoutSolution() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        outputArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
        errorReportField = new JTextField(15);

        nameLabel = new JLabel("Item name");
        numberLabel = new JLabel("# of units");
        numberLabel.setToolTipText("Number of units (or Volume in L)");
        priceLabel = new JLabel("Price per unit");
        priceLabel.setToolTipText("Price per unit (Or L) in pence");
        nameField = new JTextField(10);
        numberField = new JTextField(10);
        priceField = new JTextField(10);

        addVolumeButton = new JButton("AddVol");
        addVolumeButton.setToolTipText("Add by Volume");
        addNumberButton = new JButton("AddNum");
        addNumberButton.setToolTipText("Add by number of units");

        add(new JScrollPane(outputArea), "grow, push, wrap");
        add(errorReportField, "growx, wrap");
        add(nameLabel, "split");
        add(nameField);
        add(numberLabel);
        add(numberField);
        add(priceLabel);
        add(priceField);
        add(addVolumeButton);
        add(addNumberButton);

        pack();

        setTitle("Fuel station");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutSolution ex = new MigLayoutSolution();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]